# Как убрать стиль ссылки с Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: css, ajax

У меня есть список:

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
<ol class="genres__list">
    <li class="genre active">Все жанры</li>
    <li class="genre">@Ajax.ActionLink("Боевик", "ActionMovieSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="content"})</li>
    <li class="genre">Комедия</li>
    <li class="genre">Драма</li>
    <li class="genre">Фантастика</li>
    <li class="genre">Ужасы</li>
</ol>
```

[image: Отображение на странице]

Как убрать стили с Боевика, чтобы отображался как остальные жанры?

**UPD:**

Стили, которые использовал:

```
.left-sidebar{
width: 164px;
padding-top: 24px;
color: #141414;
font-size: 18px;
}
.genre{
padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
}

.genre:hover,
.active{
    color:#000;
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.genre a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
 }
```

По поводу стилей для ссылки: решил попробовать, т.к. ActionLink формирует ссылку. В этом я убедился в инструментах разработчика:

[image]

И, при запущенном приложении и добавлении стилей для ссылки, всё работает - ссылка отображается без подчеркивания и с другим цветом.

Comment: пробовал, это не решает проблему

Comment: Что именно показать? В вопросе есть кусок chtml-кода, пробовал писать и в css стили для .genre, и пробовал встраивать через атрибут. Позже попробую через ! important, сейчас нет возможности.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте `.genre a { text-decoration: none !important; color: black !important; }`, чтобы уже наверняка